# is it possible to create a AWS API Gateway REST API integration with a internal load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an ECS cluster with all private IPs and an internal application load balancer. I can access my application load balancer via VPN, but I want to add an API Gateway REST API and serve these APIs publicly. However, there is no option for an application load balancer in the REST API VPC Link section. I am wondering if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon API Gateway REST API only supports Network Load Balancer (NLB) for private integrations via VPCLink.

One option in this situation is to create an NLB with the existing ALB as a target group (note that this will incur additional cost). Connect the API Gateway REST API to the NLB via VPCLink.

The following references might be useful:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-nlb-for-vpclink-using-console.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/application-load-balancer-type-target-group-for-network-load-balancer/

Comment: Thanks i found out same thing. Only problem is I need to attach a certificate to nlb too otherwise nlb domain name and certificate from alb not matching and causing problems.